# Copy Destination Method Not Working for Large Amount of Data/Formula

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

Below extracted code is working perfectly if iRow is up to 40,000 (note that it leads to a total of 3,720,000 formulas...). I now need to do the same for iRow above 100,000 and it is exponentially BAD, if it finishes... I left PC turned on for more than one day and it didn't.

```
Dim iRow    As LongPtr

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Application.EnableEvents = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

WSD.Range("K2:CZ2").Copy Destination:=WSD.Range("K3:CZ" & iRow)
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
WSD.Range("K3:CZ" & iRow).Value = WSD.Range("K3:CZ" & iRow).Value

Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
Application.EnableEvents = True
```

Any light on this issue will be very much appreciated.

Configuration: Excel 2010 x64 VBA7 WIN64

Comment: Have you looked at Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb239806(v=office.12).aspx

Comment: If you have a large number of calculations you should use Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual so that Excel does not keep try to recalculate your worksheet. Just make sure to set it back to xlCalculationAutomatic at the end

Comment: I do have lots of calculations and dependancy among pasted formulas. So that, I want to preserve both : formulas and formats. Comments welcomed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This worked for me and took less than 30 seconds:

```
Sub CopyExample()
Dim iRow As Long
Dim calcState As Long

iRow = 100000
calcState = Application.Calculation
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
ActiveSheet.Range("A1:CZ1").Copy Destination:=ActiveSheet.Range("A2:CZ" & iRow)
Application.Calculation = calcState
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

You may want to do something other than `.Copy` though, if that is still giving you trouble.

**EDIT #1** Attempt to use `AutoFill` method instead of `Copy` method.  For 50,000 rows this took under 2 minutes. My dummy data has volatile `Rand()` function, and another function that is based on this function, across all columns from A1:CZ1.

```
Option Explicit

Sub CopyExample2()
Dim iRow As Long
Dim calcState As Long
Dim sourceRange As Range
Dim pasteRange As Range
Dim t As Long

t = Timer
iRow = 100000
calcState = Application.Calculation

'Turn off screenupdating, calculation, etc.'
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

Set sourceRange = ActiveSheet.Range("A1:CZ1")
Set pasteRange = ActiveSheet.Range("A1:CZ" & iRow)
    With sourceRange
        .AutoFill pasteRange
    End With

'Turn on calculation, screenupdating, etc.'
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

Debug.Print Timer - t

End Sub
```

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to comment but my "..." had already addressed all ScreenUpdating, xlCalculationManual, DisplayAlerts, EnableEvents, etc. Also, all the cells (from A to CZ) has complex formulas, including some array formulas... Still looking for a help. Many thanks.

Comment: Could you update your question to include your "..."? Might make helping a little easier.

Comment: @LuizRobertoWSilva I put dummy formula using the volatile `Rand()` formula in my test. Let me see if I can think of a better method for filling the formulas down the entire range.

Comment: @LuizRobertoWSilva see my revision above, perhaps you will have better luck with the `AutoFill` method than with `Paste`, however, I think the problem is exposed as *too many formula* in the worksheet. You will notice a workbook with millions of formulas is slow to open, save, close, etc. Perhaps there is a better way to compute these values in VBA rather than worksheet formula?

Comment: @David I have definitely had a better luck with Autofill (great deal faster). Thanks for the advice. You are right that I have too many formulas in this worksheet (iRow = 100k leads to more than 10,000,000). I can not change this design though, as it is a good approach for other purposes. I will probably combine Autofill with Range.Calculate and split this process by stock code (in my case).

Comment: I just did the mentioned split and it worked fantastic ! It took approximately one hour to process everything (three years of daily transactions). Hope this topic helps others. Thank you All.

Comment: @LuizRobertoWSilva Great news! Glad it is working for you and hopefully can help some others, too!